# Write own messaging system vs. utilize existing ones

Tags: design, message-queue, messaging

We are trying to have our own startup, with a middleware application to glue small applications with enterprise legacy systems.
for such middle-ware to function properly, we will need some sort of messaging system to make different components talk to each other in a reliable way. 
the alternatives are:

- use an existing messaging system, such as 0MQ, jBOSS, WebSphere MQ, etc.
- build our own messaging system the way we see the problem

I am more biased towards the later option for the following reasons:

- to have more control over our final product
- to avoid any licensing problems later on
- to learn about messaging while writing the code
- to invent something new, that might cost us lots of $$$ if reused an existing system

What would you do if in my shoes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are a startup I would say it depends on two things.

- Do you have any time constraints on this?
- Will building your own messaging system give you an advantage?

I don't know what kind of business your startup is in but in general its best to focus on great user experience in the beginning. The code running in the back may be awful but the user will never know that, he'll just notice if the user interface is easy to use.

So given that you have some time constraints, if the messaging system doesn't give you anything that makes a **great** difference for your application, I would use an existing one.

It's tested, it's used and there is a knowledge base.

Comment: I really like the tip of a great customer experience
Moreover, we have no time constraints so far. it is more of a side project for the time being since no real investment done. the business we target is mainly banking systems.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the freely available open source messaging systems. As long as you only *use* the library using the published API you should not experience any licensing problems.

Also look into using one of the standard APIs like (JMS,AMQ etc) so that you can "hotswap" to any messaging library your customer prefers.

In the "Enterprise" world Websphere MQ is pretty ubiquitous and many large sites have a "if its messaging it must be Websphere" policy so you should at least be compatible if you don't want to lose custom.